# Flurry Android call onStartSession from onCreate and onRestart

Tags: android, flurry

Flurry recommends calling its onStartSession method from onStart. In my implementation I need to call it from onCreate due to dependencies on other services. Is it possible to call it from both onCreate and onRestart to cover all activity lifecycle cases. (I am referring to this lifecycle [image: diagram]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation, `onStartSession` will "start or continue a Flurry session" :

http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/android/v3.3/classcom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1_flurry_agent.html

in other words, you should be able to call it as often as you like (onCreate, onStart, onResume, onRestart... put it in all of them if you like).